# Conditions for integrable function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Define a function of $y>0,$
$$f(y)=\int_0^{1}x^{p-1}e^{-\frac{x}{y}}dx,$$
where $p>0.$  Denote
$$I(a_1,a_2)=\iint_{0<y_2<y_1<\infty} y_1^{-a_1}y_2^{-a_2}f(y_1)f(y_2) dy_1 dy_2.$$
**Question:** What is the sufficient and necessary conditions of $(a_1,a_2)$, satisfying $I(a_1,a_2)<\infty$?

Comment: In my answer, I supposed that parameters $p$ and $a$ are real.

Comment: I think we need utilize the restriction $0<y_2<y_1<\infty.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

I suppose that the first thing to do is to clarify what is $f(y)$
$$f(y)=\int_0^{1}x^{p-1}e^{-\frac{x}{y}}\,dx=y^p \left(\Gamma (p)-\Gamma \left(p,\frac{1}{y}\right)\right) \qquad \text{if} \qquad p >0$$

Now,
$$\int y^{-a} f(y)\,dy=\frac{y^{p+1-a} \left(\Gamma (p)-\Gamma \left(p,\frac{1}{y}\right)\right)+\Gamma
   \left(a-1,\frac{1}{y}\right)}{p+1-a}$$
$$\int_0^t y^{-a} f(y)\,dy=\frac{t^{p+1-a} \left(\Gamma (p)-\Gamma \left(p,\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)+\Gamma
   \left(a-1,\frac{1}{t}\right)}{p+1-a}\qquad \text{if} \qquad a-p <1$$

I am sure that you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think $a_1<p+1, a_2<p+1$ are one sufficient condition.  We need utilize the restriction $0<y_2<y_1<\infty$. 
I guess the sufficient and necessary condition is some thing like
$a_1<p+1, a_1+a_2<2p+2,$ or $a_2<p+1, a_1+a_2<2p+2.$ But I am not sure it is right. I am looking forward to your reply.